# Email an error message with Python [Username and Password not accepted]

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, error-handling

I am trying to send my exact error message via email however it does not seem to be sending anything. I have removed try blocks but no errors are displayed. I have tried the following:

```
try:
    #Value here
except OSError as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
    sender = "h####@gmail.com"
    receiver = ["a#####.com"]
    message = traceback.print_exc()

    try:
        session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        session.ehlo()
        session.starttls()
        session.ehlo()
        session.login(sender,'dadwadwa')
        session.sendmail(sender,receiver,message)
        session.quit()

    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: There are two parts to this code: Getting a traceback in string format and sending an email. Please seperate those parts and only ask the part that raises the question.  

For me your code example works and sends an email with a reasonable text.

Comment: Can you run the commands interactively and check the output? Both login and sendmail give fairly descriptive output.

Comment: `.sendmail` expects a list of recipient addresses. Does your `receiver` variable have this format?

Comment: @VPfB I am getting an output now.  It gives me: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials e17sm18346476pfb.53 - gsmtp')

Comment: I think your problem is Gmail.  Specifically Captcha.  Use another provider as code works alright for me.

Comment: @DallasClov So you have find the cause. You may need to disable the 2-step verification as google writes on their support webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain easier way to do what you are asking.
Something along the lines of:

```
def raise_email(self, e):
    SendEmail()
    raise e
```